# Disable Drag and Drop in Modern View Document Library - Sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am looking for a way - Disable Drag and Drop in Modern View Document Library - Sharepoint online.

Any Help will be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

We cannot disable Drag and Drop in Modern View Document Library because the class name changes in modern view and dragdrop.js file.

Currently, custom JavaScript embedded via User Custom Actions is not supported in SharePoint online.

For more information about customizing modern lists and libraries, check the following article:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/pnp_articles/modern-experience-customizations-customize-lists-and-libraries?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#overview-of-the-customization-options

[Source](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a072605c-68f1-4927-93d1-f4ab0fed4ba6/disable-drag-and-drop-in-modern-view-document-library-sharepoint-online?forum=onlineservicessharepoint)

Answer (score 0):

Per my knowledge, you will not be able to disable drag&drop OOB in SPO. It may be possible if you create a custom SPFx solution