# How to disable drag and drop feature in modern SharePoint library using SPFx?

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, spfx, spfx-extensions

I have a requirement to disable drag and drop feature in modern SharePoint document library using SPFx application customizer.

User should not drag and drop files into a folder or into a library.

Can anyone help me with code snippet to disable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See: [Disable Drag and Drop in Modern View Document Library - Sharepoint online](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/274469/disable-drag-and-drop-in-modern-view-document-library-sharepoint-online)

Disabling the drag and drop feature in a modern SharePoint document library using SPFx might be challenging. This is because the class name changes in the modern view and the `dragdrop.js` file is not available. Custom JavaScript embedded via User Custom Actions is not supported in SharePoint Online